# get html view in laravel and put it in array container (laravel 5.2)

Tags: laravel

Trying to get the view and put it in array container. I used this code but unfortunately not working:

```
$data['list'] = User::get();    
return response()->json(['view' => view('table-data', $data), 'count'=>10]);

//output is:
{"view":{},"count":10}
//view is null
```

I want to get the view and render as $('tbody').html(view);
Thanks

Comment: You want to display data in table body right?

Comment: the data is already rendered in table-data.blade.php, then i want to get that and put it in array container so that i can add more array item that i want. basically i want my html view act as an array value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved it using **view()->render()**:

```
return response()->json(['view' => view('table-data', $data)->render(), 'count'=>10]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to return view

1) return view

```html
Syntax :return view('view_name', ['var_name' => 'value']);

Example : return view('table-data',['count'=>10]);
```

2) return view with compact function

```html
Syntax : return view('view_name', compact('var1','var2','var3'));

Example : return view('table-data',compact('count'));
```